# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed in IIS Express

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-express

When issuing a perfectly cromulent verb to a local IIS Express web-site under Visual Studio 2013:

```
CROMULENT http://localhost:7579/Handler.ashx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7579
```

the server responds with the error:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
```

That is a request to a *"generic handler"* *(i.e. `.ashx`)*. If if i try again to a *static* resource:

```
SCHWIFTY http://localhost:7579/Default.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7579
```

the server responds with the error:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
```

This is all by way to trying to use HTTP verbs:

```
DELETE http://localhost:7579/Handler.ashx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7579

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE

PUThttp://localhost:7579/Handler.ashx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7579

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
```

This question has been asked to death, sometimes by me. But nobody has ever come up with a solution.

### </Question>

**Microsoft's Bug**

The problem, fundamentally, is that Microsoft ships IIS and IISExpress broken by default. Rather than handling HTTP verbs, as a web-server is required to do, they don't handle verbs.

This can most easily be seen when managing full IIS running on Windows Server. Pick any of the built-in handlers (e.g. the cshtml handler), and you can see that someone thought it would be *hilarious* if it only worked with `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST`, and `DEBUG` verbs:

[image]

rather than correctly implementing support for HTTP in an HTTP server.

The question becomes:

- why ***exactly*** doesn't it work
- how ***exactly*** to fix it
- how to fix it in ***IIS Express*** (without any management tools)
- ***why*** it continues to be shipped, year after year, broken

### Question 1. Why doesn't it work?

The first question is why doesn't it work. Let's look at an IIS server where we've removed every handler except the basic **Static** file handler:

[image]

The handler is configured to all *all* verbs:

[image]

The only handler left is set to allow **any** verb. Yet if we issue a request to the web server we get the error:

```
DELETE http://scratch.avatopia.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: scratch.avatopia.com

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
```

> Why is this happening?

Why didn't it work? Where is the configuration option that says:

- `GET`
- `HEAD`
- `OPTIONS`
- `TRACE`

because the server itself is saying those are the only supported verbs.

Yet if we change it to a `GET` it works fine:

```
GET http://scratch.avatopia.com/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: scratch.avatopia.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
```

### Question 2. How to fix it?

The common wisdom is to remove **WebDAV**. Nobody knows what WebDAV is, how it could be a problem, why it is a problem, or why it exists if it only causes problems. WebDAV can be removed as a handler from the IIS administration user interface:

[image]

which is **identical** to adding a `remove` entry from the `handlers` section in `web.config` (the UI itself adds the entry to web.config for you):

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Except this doesn't work. So how do we *fix* it?

Starting with IIS it seems that WebDAV has become even more of a virus. Rather than simply disabling it as a handler, [you have to completely install or remove it as a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8):

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

That sounds like a reason idea, except in my test case, on IIS 7.5, WebDAV is both not installed, and removed as a module:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 19:19:42 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

So, if we can figure out how to solve the problem, we can answer question number two.

### Question 3. How to fix it in IIS Express

Starting with Visual Studio 2013<sup>1</sup>, Visual Studio no longer uses a mini web-server called Cassini. It uses a portable install of IIS Express itself (i.e. IIS Express Windows feature doesn't need to be installed).

Most of the above fix (attempts) (fail) in IIS. But nobody has dealt with them in IIS Express of Visual Studio 2013 (which is how this question is different from any others).

### Question 4. Why does this keep happening?

It's been over 15 years, and this still keeps happening. There must be a *good* reason why IIS does not function as a web-server. But what is it? I've not been able to find any knowledge base article, or blog post, explaining why the IIS team refuses to function correctly.

### Bonus Reading

- The most popular Stackoverflow question for this problem: [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)

### Research Effort

- [HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed, with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955747/http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed-with-post) *(no answer, php)*
- [HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238585/http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed) *(no answer)*
- [POST verb not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446604/post-verb-not-allowed) *(php)*
- [HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed in ASP.net MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019130/http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed-in-asp-net-mvc5) *(no answer, mvc)*
- [JQuery File Uploader = error 405 IIS8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363032/jquery-file-uploader-error-405-iis8-5) *(jquery no answer)*
- [IIS 7.5 405 Method Not Allowed for PUT from StaticFileModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629067/iis-7-5-405-method-not-allowed-for-put-from-staticfilemodule) *(no answer, static module, iis)*
- [The HTTP verb POST used to access path is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238080/the-http-verb-post-used-to-access-path-is-not-allowed) *("don't use verbs")*
- [http error 405 method not allowed error with web.API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410041/http-error-405-method-not-allowed-error-with-web-api) *(uninstall WebDAV; already isn't)*
- [Handling Perl IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966866/handling-perl-iis-7-5) *(perl)*
- [HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed using Jquery ajax get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088352/http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed-using-jquery-ajax-get) *(ajax)*
- [What causes an HTTP 405 "invalid method (HTTP verb)" error when POSTing a form to PHP on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400210/what-causes-an-http-405-invalid-method-http-verb-error-when-posting-a-form-t) *(iis6, ftp, php)*
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1648594.aspx *("have you tried pinging your computer")*
- [Angular $resource POST/PUT to WebAPI 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483355/angular-resource-post-put-to-webapi-405-method-not-allowed) *(try removing WebDAV handlder and WebDAV module)*
- [Http Error 405.0 - method not allowed iis 7.5 module staticfilemodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519201/http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed-iis-7-5-module-staticfilemodule) *(no solution)*
- [Unable to set up WebDAV with IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389309/unable-to-set-up-webdav-with-iis-7) *(trying to *setup* webdav)*
- [Android SOAP request is returning HTTP Response 405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777466/android-soap-request-is-returning-http-response-405) *(no solution)*
- [wcf service doesn't allow POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930742/wcf-service-doesnt-allow-post) *(wcf)*
- [WebAPI Delete not working - 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619075/webapi-delete-not-working-405-method-not-allowed) *(WebAPI; remove WebDAV)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to pick up on a bit of frustration in the question, so the *actual* question is a bit unclear. What specifically is it that you are trying, but failing, to do? What do you expect of the answer?

Anyway, based on this comment in the question:

> This is all by way to trying to use HTTP verbs:

and the corresponding samples involving a generic handler, I'll take a stab at showing what is needed to make it possible to `PUT` and `DELETE` a generic handler.

In order to allow `PUT` and `DELETE` on a generic handler, you must allow it in the `web.config` of the application. To do that you should register a handler for `*.ashx` as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-WithPutDelete"
            path="*.ashx"
            verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"
            type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory"
            resourceType="Unspecified"
            requireAccess="Script"
            preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Depending on how you originally set up the web site/application, there may or may not be a handler registered for `type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory"` in your `web.config` file. If there is one, you should be able to just modify that entry and add the verbs you want to allow.

You'll note that this entry has the `preCondition="integratedMode"`. This should, I believe, work when debugging in Visual Studio using IIS Express. In a real IIS deployment, the handler registration may need to be modified to match the application pool that will run the application. For an application running in classic mode (not integrated), it would look something like this (not tested so may be wrong):

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit-WithPutDelete" 
            path="*.ashx" 
            verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" 
            modules="IsapiModule" 
            scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
            preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" 
            responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

The exact details would depend on the framework version an bit-ness of the application pool.

If you are debugging in Visual Studio using IIS Express, you should have a look at the `applicationhost.config` which sets up a lot of the defaults regarding IIS Express. It is located in:

```
My Documents\IISExpress\config
```

The untested handler registration above for a classic pipeline application pool is a slight modification of a handler registration in that file. There are in my environment 6 separate entries for `*.ashx`, with varying preconditions, in that file.

It might be a good idea to explicitly remove all of these in your `web.config` if you want to have your own registration which allows `PUT` and `DELETE`. Not all of them would actually be active/registered at the same time since the preconditions are (I suppose) mutually exclusive, but at least for me it works to just remove them all, one after the other. In my environment the section with the removes looks like this:

```
<remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
<remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
<remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0"/>
<remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
<remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0"/>
<remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64"/>
```

Hope this shines at least a bit of light into dark places!

Comment: Holy schnikies! I've been searching all day and every answer is to "remove WebDAV" or modify the "applicationHost.config" file. None of these worked for me. We are using the ASP.NET WebForms framework with UrlRewrite 2.0 installed to handle friendly urls. This is hands down the most elegant solution I've found. Bravo!

Comment: 5 years later and this is still a problem!  Any idea how to fix this for .NET Core 3.1 and Visual Studio 2019.  When I try the solution here my local web site no longer starts up, if I have a Handlers section in a web.config file.

Comment: @AntWaters .Net Core is a different beast. This answer is likely of no use for you. Suggest you post a new question where you describe your situation in detail. I'm sure someone will be able to guide you in the right direction...

Comment: Thanks.  I have found some pointers on the following, but none of the solutions there work for me yet:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188895/asp-net-core-with-iis-http-verb-not-allowed

Answer (score 5):

okay so i ran into this same exact problem on IIS 7.5 when trying to PUT or DELETE it returned a 405.

i was specifically trying to setup a MEAN stack with IISnode module. when accessing the static HTML file IIS was serving up i was able to GET and PUSH but not PUT or DELETE.

-- the problem --

i believe that the issue is with IIS server itself. take a look at this post here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saurabh_singh/2010/12/10/anonymous-put-in-webdav-on-iis-7-deprecated/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2021641

it appears that IIS no longer allows Anonymous PUT or DELETE

so in the end i just went with a nodejs webserver instead

-- however --

i have not tried this but perhaps you might want to look into modifying the IIS system config file itself called the ApplicationHost.config located here:

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

make sure to use notepad with administrator privileges

let me know how it goes and i might try and do this later when i have time

Comment: This was exactly my issue as well, by adding the handlers to remove webdav in the node app's web.config as stated in the original post, PUT and DELETE started working again.

Comment: this is very usefull, it's working. I try some solution but I think this is best

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of talk about removing WebDAV and that will fix the problem - but if you're wondering what WebDAV is and what its used for, check out this page:

https://www.cloudwards.net/what-is-webdav/

Answer (score 1):

Holy Damn, many research these 2 days....

No WebDav installed, no typical handler modifications (`SimpleHandlerFactory`, `ExtensionlessUrl`)

For those using any PHP Frameworks just as: Laravel, CakePHP etc

I couldn't make IIS Failed Tracing Logs work, so...

All I did was, modify PHP handler [MODIFY: **php-X_VERSION**]:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="php-X_VERSION" />
    <add name="php-X_VERSION" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files\PHP\X_VERSION\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: It is quite disheartening that we have to remove something and then re-add it correctly. We really wish Microsoft would just do things correctly out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I have no WebDAV installed, and am running IIS Express from VS2019. After some digging, I came upon the applicationhost.config file used by IIS Express, and ended up with a solution by changing my own project **web.config** file. In the system.webServer/handlers section, add the following:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0"/>
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0"/>
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64"/>
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

All this does, is it adds the word "PUT" to the verb attribute of each handler.
I also have to add that I am working on an older project and created the API endpoints with *.aspx files, which is why other solutions found googling did not work. So if you are using VS2019 and get the error **405.0 - Method not Allowed** and you **already removed WebDAV** and expose your API with .aspx files this might work.