# HTTP POST not allowed in simple webpage in Visual Studio 2015 (405.0 error)

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, http-post, iis-express

In Visual Studio 2015, I created a new ASP.NET empty website.  I wanted to try [this sample shopping cart](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/create-client-side-shopping-cart/).  I added a very simple index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Winery</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.shop.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="site">
    <header id="masthead">
        <h1>Winery <span class="tagline">Wines for web developers since 1999</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="products">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img src="images/wine1.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-description" data-name="Wine #1" data-price="5">
                        <h3 class="product-name">Wine #1</h3>
                        <p class="product-price">&euro; 5</p>
                        <form class="add-to-cart" action="cart.html" method="post">
                            <div>
                                <label for="qty-1">Quantity</label>
                                <input type="text" name="qty-1" id="qty-1" class="qty" value="1" />
                            </div>
                            <p><input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" /></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.
```

This is supposed to POST an item in the cart.html page. (I can post code for the cart.html, but I think the error is happening before that page)  If I just open up Windows Explorer and find the index.html and just open that manually in Chrome and click the button the -POST WORKS FINE-, but for reason it doesn't in VS2015 (nor my Azure Web App Service).

When I test the site locally, in VS the process shows 'iisexpress.exe' is running, so I assume IIS Express is what serving up the pages by default.  My web.config for this project is the default and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In looking online I've seen that POST could be disabled by default.. is that true?!  If so, I'd think many people would have this issue.  I can't believe I've had such a hard time finding an answer to this seemingly simple issue.

Also, as I mentioned I am publishing this to an AZURE Web App Service, so I don't think any local changes to IIS config files is going to change anything when I publish.  I think I need to change the web.config to make this work in Azure.

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147406/http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed-in-iis-express) and all of the links in the 'research efforts' section. Nothing.  I see all the 'similar questions' to the right as I'm typing this.. they seem related but no solutions work for me.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, it seems that I needed to change the file extension to .aspx for the POST to work.  Once I changed from .html to .aspx then the post worked as expected.  (Seems that the error messages could have SAID that so I didn't waste hours of my life trying to figure out why POST wasn't working)