# Why I cannot Login the using c# and mysql in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am beginner in developing a website using ASP.Net

Please Help me. so that i can pursue my career. Thanks in Advance

I am creating a login script using c# and I want to call it in javascript.

But it after I Logged in, The Login page will only refreshing.

And there is an exception said `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Extensions.dll`

So here is my code :

HTML

```
<form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control material" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control material" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-block btn-info text-uppercase waves">Login</button>

              </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        AuthenticateUser(username, password)
    });
});

function AuthenticateUser(username, password) {
    var value = "{'email':'" + username
                   + "','pass':'" + password
                   + "'}";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../WebService/csLogin.asmx/loadEmployeeAccount',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: value,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            var cells = eval("(" + response.d + ")");
            console.log(cells);
            if (cells.length >= 1) {
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
            } else {
                alert("Invalid Email/Password");
                document.getElementById("username").focus();
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        }
    });
}
```

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string loadEmployeeAccount(string email, string pass)
    {
        List<Auth> mylist = new List<Auth>();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = @email AND password = @pass", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                int user = 0;
                if (dr["userType"].ToString() == "")
                    user = 1;
                else
                    user = Convert.ToInt32(dr["userType"].ToString());
                mylist.Add(new Auth
                {
                    user_id = dr["user_id"].ToString(),
                    username = dr["username"].ToString()
                });
            }
            dr.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsn = jss.Serialize(mylist);
        return jsn;
    }
```

And here is the image on the console.
[image]
[image]
Can someone help me with this?? any help will much be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: add break point to loadEmployeeAccount ass see where is error occurred in which line.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem the debugger cannot hit the breakpoint.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem Please see 2nd image sir

Comment: The error is right there, at the 4th point of the error webpage. You’ve used a POST method on the page request, but you should’ve used GET

Comment: @DavideVitali I already change the method sir, but again nothing happens and it always reloading when i click the button login

Comment: @BooLaTeh the Ajax call has POST type, what have you changed?

Comment: @DavideVitali this one sir `type: POST` to `type: GET`

Comment: @DavideVitali I tried to breakpoint my c# code sir. but the debugger does not hit it. what should be the possible cause of this?

Comment: Instead of [WebMethod] use [HttpPost] in your C# code. Also if you want to send JSON via Ajax, you would need to do `data: { "json": JSON.stringify(value) }` and then in your C# code it would be `[HttpPost]
    public string loadEmployeeAccount(string json){//your code with json string}`

Comment: @RahulSharma the `[HttpPost]` is underlined by red. is there any reference that i need to remove the error?

Comment: @RahulSharma `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'UseHttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) benchmark(1) C:\Users\SDG08\Desktop\benchmark\App_Code\wsLogin.cs 27 Active`

Error still exist

Comment: @RahulSharma Sir? how to split and get the username and password in your code in c# `data: { "json": JSON.stringify(value) }`

Comment: In your C# code, once you have you JSON string which is `json`, you can do something like this `dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));` and then do get your username and password: `string username = jsondata["email"]; string password=jsondata["pass"]`

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you are using ASP.NET ASMX: Using `[WebMethod]` is fine on your C# code. Add the following references to your web.config file: `<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>`

Comment: It always error sir

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147406/http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed-in-iis-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in order to achieve your functionality follow these steps:

In your AJAX, do the following to convert your `value` string as JSON and then send it to your WebMethod:

```
data: {"json": JSON.stringify(value)}
```

Then decorate your class with:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

to allow POST requests via AJAX to your WebMethod.

And then in your WebMethod, do the following to parse your JSON string that you received from your AJAX call:

```
[WebMethod]
public string loadEmployeeAccount(string json)
{
dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
string username = jsondata["email"]; 
string password=jsondata["pass"]

//Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is issue in passing value from ajax call please make change in your javascript function to call webmethod

```
function AuthenticateUser(username, password) {
    var value = {'email':username,
                 'pass':password};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../WebService/csLogin.asmx/loadEmployeeAccount',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(value),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            var cells = eval("(" + response.d + ")");
            console.log(cells);
            if (cells.length >= 1) {
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
            } else {
                alert("Invalid Email/Password");
                document.getElementById("username").focus();
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens sir.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with pure ASP.NET, as I use MVC, but I guess they’re just the same under the hood, so this is a wild guess.

First thing, within your Ajax function you have to change the type of action from `POST` to `GET`, your error webpage is explicitly telling you you’re not supposed to send data through a POST action, after all.

```
type: ‘GET’
```

Second thing, i think the way you’re passing data to the web method is wrong: you’re passing a single literal object when your method is expecting two strings. By changing this, things should work as expected:

```
data: {
    email: username,
    pass: password
}
```

also, delete the `dataType: ‘JSON’`