Windows IIS: Virtual directory returning 405 with PUT request
I have a virtual directory set up on IIS, which I can access fine through my web browser and I can successfully execute GET requests using the PowerShell command:
Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri 'http://my-directory/' -OutFile my-file.
However, when I try a PUT request e.g.
Invoke-WebRequest -Method PUT -Uri 'http://my-directory/' -InFile my-file
I receive the following error HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed. The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.
(full error message here)
I have tried all the solutions I've found online including removing WebDAV module and handler from the web config and converting the virtual directory to an application. I have made sure all verbs are allowed with the staticfile handler mentioned in the error.

Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/37197698/18667225 ?

This problem may also occur because the client makes a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) request by using an HTTP method that doesn't comply with the HTTP specifications.
Make sure that the client sends a request that contains a valid HTTP method. To do so, follow these steps:

Select Start, type Notepad in the Start Search box, right-click Notepad, and then select Run as administrator.

On the File menu, select Open. In the File name box, type %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config, and then select Open.

In the ApplicationHost.config file, locate the  tag.

Make sure that all the handlers use valid HTTP methods.

Save the ApplicationHost.config file.



Unfortunately, as I mentioned, I've tried this. I don't think WebDAV is the problem.

I've re-edited my answer, please try again.
